# C# label tooltip is showing up several times

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, hover, label, tooltip

I think I have an unusual problem, alot of questions about tooltips are: why doesn't it show up, or why not multiple times.
however my problem is that when I hover over my tooltip label, the tooltip shows up several times, if I move my mouse slowly over the label it shows for every pixel.
I tried something like: `ToolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;`
but that doesn't seem to have any effect.
I also tried using `label1_MouseEnter`, and a `label1_MouseLeave`, but can't get that working either.

I hope someone can help me out

this is the code where it all has to happen: :)

```
    private void label1_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Enter Help box texboxes
        System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
        ToolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
        ToolTip1.Show("Enter the Drive letter in the first textbox" + "\n" + "Enter the submap in the second textbox", label1);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that on hover? It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do

Comment: Just set the Tooltip property of label control if you are using asp:Label

Comment: No when i hold my mouse on the label, the tooltip shows up like 2 or 3 times, or when i move slowly over the label, it spams the tooltip box. so it has to show up just 1 at a time

Comment: The tooltip is generated every time the hover event is triggered, you should move the creation out of the block and just set it (is it winform ?)

Comment: What do you mean by move the creation out of the block and just set it? can you give a little example? i'm still pretty new ;) yes i'm using Winform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the hover event handler to create the tooltip, you're causing a new `ToolTip` object to be created and associated with the label each time the user hovers over it.  You'll notice the first time you hover over it you see one tooltip, but subsequent hovers will create additional tooltips.

Rather than creating the tooltip in the label's hover event, you can simply create it once when the form is created.  The `SetToolTip()` method will cause the tooltip to be associated with the provided control and will behave as a normal tooltip (only showing when the user hovers over the control).

For example, you could call `SetToolTip()` in the constructor of the form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new ToolTip().SetToolTip(label1, "Enter the Drive letter in the first textbox" + "\n" + "Enter the submap in the second textbox");
    }
```

Alternatively, you could create the tooltip in the form's load event handler.

Comment: Ooh, got it, awesome, after setting it in the form like this i used: ToolTip1.Show("", label1); in the labe1_hover and it worked, thansk!

Comment: You can remove the label1_hover event handler completely.  `SetToolTip()` will automatically make the tooltip appear when the user hovers over the control you name in the method call.